# Find the distance between a list of points in two columns with one list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, euclidean-distance

I need to create a column that will be made up of a list of lists that represents the distance between points. I am trying to create this list of distances in one list comprehension or the most efficient way possible.

Here is the beginning data frame `df`

```
ID        list_1              list_2
00    [(10,2),(5,7)]      [(11,3),(9,9)]
01    [(1,7)]             [(9,1)(2,1),(6,3)]
02    [(4,2),(9,4)]       [(3,7)]
```

Here is the ending `df` data frame that I want. Essentially for each row, every tuple in column `list_2` will need to find the distance between itself and every tuple in column `list_1`.

```
ID        list_1              list_2               distances
00    [(10,2),(5,7)]      [(11,3),(9,9)]    [[1.41,7.21],[7.07,4.47]]
01    [(1,7)]             [(9,1)(2,1)]      [[10.0,6.08]]
```

I end up doing six list comprehensions before I get to the end goal but I am sure there is a more efficient way.

what I am doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import math
```

step 1

```
df['x'] = [[s[1] for s in object_slice] for object_slice in df['list_1']]
```

step 2

```
df['y'] = [[s[1] for s in object_slice] for object_slice in df['list_1']]
```

step 3

```
df['dist_p1'] = [[(df['x'][a] - s[1],df['y'][a] - s[0]) for s in object_slice]for a, object_slice in enumerate(df['list_2'])]
```

step 4

```
df['dist_p2'] = [[s[0] for s in object_slice] for object_slice in df['dist_p1']]
```

step 5

```
df['dist_p3'] = [[s[1] for s in object_slice] for object_slice in df['dist_p1']]
```

step 6

```
df['distances'] = [[[round(math.hypot(s2,df['dist_p2'][a][b][c]),2) for c, s2 in enumerate(s)] for b,s in enumerate(object_slice)] for a, object_slice in enumerate(df['dist_p1'])]
```

Comment: In places where you have multiple points in either list1 or list2 (or both): how do you wish the output to be structured? a sublist for every point in list1, or a sublist for every point in list2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP:

Your original code throw error at step3, So I cannot reproduce your result.

However, your calculation logic seem to be inconsistent between row `00` and row `01` in your example result.

Because:
In row `00`,

```
[[1.41,7.21],[7.07,4.47]]=[[distance((11,3),(10,2)),distance((11,3)(5,7))],
                           [distance((9,9),(10,2)),distance((9,9),(5,7))]]
```

Here `list_2` is the outer loop, `list_1` is the inner loop.

However in row `01`,

```
[[10.0,6.08]] = [[distance((1,7),(9,1)), distance((1,7),(2,1))]]
```

Here `list_1` is the outer loop, `list_2` is the inner loop.

In other words, the order of the nested loop logic is different between row `00` and row `01` in your example result.

---

However, here is what I will do if I use `list_1` as outer loop.

```py
df['distances']=df.apply(lambda row:[[round(math.hypot(i[0]-j[0],i[1]-j[1]),2) for j in row['list_2']] for i in row['list_1']],axis=1)
```

Returns:

```
    list_1              list_2              distances
0   [(10, 2), (5, 7)]   [(11, 3), (9, 9)]   [[1.41, 7.07], [7.21, 4.47]]
1   [(1, 7)]            [(9, 1), (2, 1)]    [[10.0, 6.08]]
```

If you need to use `list_2` as outer loop,  you can simply swap `list_1` and `list_2` in the `lambda` function.

Comment: Hey this worked perfectly. Could you possibly break down how your lambda function works? If I just try running the nested list comprehension part it won't run because you can't subtract tuples from one another. But it seems that adding the lambda function is acting like another nested listed comprehension that then allows you to subtract the values?

Comment: using your answer as a base I was able to create an answer using only one list comprehension  `df['distances'] = [[[round(math.hypot(i[0]-j[0], i[1]-j[1]),2) for i in b]for j in df['list_2'][a]]for a,b in enumerate(df['list_1'])]`